# Time Series Regression Correlation

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study

[image]

If I recall correctly, the equation for $R^2$ is $\frac{SST-SSE}{SST}$

So is the answer simply, $\frac{60-40}{60}=\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Refer to the book of Douglas C. Montgomery on Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The regression model fitted is a polynomial regression model, so you may better search for Polynomial Regression model in the book of Douglas C. Montgomery on "Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis".

Answer (score 0):

Please, you must review the definition of **R - squared** Find here the right answer.
[image: Solution][image: Solution-suit]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll study this and ask if I'm lost :D